# Screenshot con html2canvas error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, html2canvas, screenshot

Tengo una forma de reportar error en el desarrollo que estoy haciendo. Al ejecutar el reporte, se toma un screenshot de body que se está trabajando, pero el problema es que el arriba del body queda esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que es un recuadro balanco como con texto amontonado y por debajo de él queda el body del screenshot.

Este es mi codigo para el creenshot:

```
        this._SPINNER.show();
        html2canvas(document.body)
            .then((canvas: any) => {
                this._SPINNER.hide();
                let urls: any[] = [];
                let url = canvas.toDataURL();
                urls.push(url);
                this._DIALOG.open(ReportDialogComponent, {
                    disableClose: true,
                    width: '720px',
                    data: { url: urls, identifier: this.identifier },
                });
            })
            .catch((error: any) => {
                console.error(error);
                this._SPINNER.hide();
            });
```

Espero me pueda ayudar.

Comment: En ese código no se ve el uso de html2canvas, ni sabemos qué es la variable `can`. Te recomiendo que crees un [mcve], tras leer [ask]

Comment: Listo @Pablo ya agregué el codigo de html2canvas, espero me puedas ayudar.

Comment: ¿Hay algún error en consola? Parece que los CSS no se están aplicando al generar el canvas, quizá no tiene acceso al fichero css con las reglas a aplicar.

Comment: Intenta realizar un scroll top en la pantalla antes de que tomes la captura.